# How to call a file periodically in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to load file periodically (like once per n seconds) to redraw webpage as the file changes.

The file contains JSON data, which is used in the webpage using Google Map API.

I know that it isn't a clean way compare to refresh page only when there is change in file(fs.watch?) but I just want it to work first, clean up later.

The code of get request part looks like:

```
var xmlhttp, jsona;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'url/JsonOri.txt', false);
xmlhttp.send();
jsona = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

This will call JsonOri.txt only once, but I want it to call the data periodically so it 'looks like' it's refreshed.

If the question seems not clear enough, please leave comment so I can improve about it.

Full script looks like below:

```
    <script>
    var xmlhttp, jsona;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://url/JsonOri.txt', false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    jsona = xmlhttp.responseText;  
    var jsond = JSON.parse(jsona);
    function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for(out = 0; out < jsond.stories.length; out++)
    {
        var coary = [];
        for( i = 0; i < jsond.stories[out].items.length; i++ )
        {   
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(jsond.stories[out].items[i].latitude, jsond.stories[out].items[i].longitude);
            coary.push(position);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: jsond.stories[0].items[i].place_name
            });
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(
            {
                path: coary,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
        }
    }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(7);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function reqListener () {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting code in function and using `setInterval(function(){}, n)`?

Comment: May I ask how to use that function? Is it like: function(){ CODE ON QUESTION}, n) or is there other way? // what is the unit for n?

Comment: Yes, you are right. N is how often repeat this function in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your code in a function like this:

```
function yourfunction() {
    var xmlhttp, jsona;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'url/JsonOri.txt', false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    jsona = xmlhttp.responseText;  
}
```

Then call it in `setInterval` function:

```
var i = setInterval(yourfunction, 5000);
```

where `5000` is the period.

**Edit**

```
<script>
var xmlhttp, jsona;
var map;
var bounds;
var jsond;
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

function yourfunction() {

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://url/JsonOri.txt', false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    jsona = xmlhttp.responseText;  
    jsond = JSON.parse(jsona);

    initialized();

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


function initialize() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for(out = 0; out < jsond.stories.length; out++)
    {
        var coary = [];
        for( i = 0; i < jsond.stories[out].items.length; i++ )
        {   
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(jsond.stories[out].items[i].latitude,       jsond.stories[out].items[i].longitude);
            coary.push(position);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: jsond.stories[0].items[i].place_name
            });
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(
            {
                path: coary,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
}

    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed',   function(event) {
this.setZoom(7);
google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
</script>
```

I think this will work, tried it and provide me feedback

Comment: I would recommend storing the function setInterval in a variable, so that it can be cancelled at anytime.

Comment: hmm, wrapping up a part of code makes other part complain about it. like, I'm using google Map Api but wrapping whole script part causes loading nothing(not even on console), and wrapping only the request part obviously makes it complain about jsona undefined. defining jsona outside of function causes unexpected token u which means xmlhttp.responseText doesn't save on jsona properly, or reseted.

Comment: can you edit your question with the code that you tried, it's easier for me to determine the error

Comment: Sounds like you need to put the code that uses `jsona` inside the function as well.

Comment: well as I commented before, if I put whole code in it, it shows nothing but white blank page, with no error on the console.

Comment: if all your code is inside a function, then you need a way to call/execute that functions. Either a click event, an onload event..something.

Comment: jsond is undefined - I guess jsond is still trapped inside the 'yourfunction'  which causes problem.

Comment: I see, just place `jsond` outside of the function.